# How can I update mysql in Javascript and PHP without having to start a new connection on every request?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have some training videos in which I update the database once per second.  The working code that I have passes seconds watched from JS to PHP to Mysql.  The problem that I am having is that it will not update unless I start a new connection with every request (every second).  Is there a better way?  My JS code;

```
//AJAX save 'seconds played' values to database
function updatedb() {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { 
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/userupdate.php?q=" + userID + "&r=" +     (medeno[index][0]) + "&s=" + index, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

and my PHP code (seperate file.php);

```
<?php

//Get values
$userID=$_GET['q'];
$secc=$_GET['r'];
$index=$_GET['s'];

$userID=(int)$userID;
$secc=(int)$secc;
$index=(int)$index;

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "medeno_user", "cr3134", "medeno_users");


//Update database 1 case per video course
switch ($index) {
    case 1: $stmt1=$mysqli->prepare('UPDATE users set videoSec1=? WHERE     userID=?'); break;
    case 2: $stmt1=$mysqli->prepare('UPDATE users set videoSec2=? WHERE userID=?'); break;
    case 3: $stmt1=$mysqli->prepare('UPDATE users set videoSec3=? WHERE userID=?'); break;
    case 4: $stmt1=$mysqli->prepare('UPDATE users set videoSec4=? WHERE userID=?'); break;
    case 5: $stmt1=$mysqli->prepare('UPDATE users set videoSec5=? WHERE userID=?'); break;
    case 6: $stmt1=$mysqli->prepare('UPDATE users set videoSec6=? WHERE userID=?'); break;
    case 7: $stmt1=$mysqli->prepare('UPDATE users set videoSec7=? WHERE userID=?'); break;
    case 8: $stmt1=$mysqli->prepare('UPDATE users set videoSec8=? WHERE userID=?'); break;}

$stmt1->bind_param('ii',$secc,$userID);
$stmt1->execute();
$stmt1->close();
```

Comment: And you talking about TCP connections? How do you know you start it each time? Most servers/browsers already keep connections alive.

Comment: Use Persistent DB connection to avoid connection creation overhead on each request. if your PHP installation is not CGI.

Comment: Great answers!  Persistent connections is new to me and would have been perfect, except Hostgator only allows persistent connections for 15 seconds, then cuts it off.  From the first answer, maybe I can just remove the $stmt->close() from the code.